# Converting NFA to DFA without epsilon transition function

Tags: computer-science, finite-automata, computation-theory

Based on my understanding an epsilon is always required to convert NFA to DFA. 
Is it possible to convert below NFA to DFA? If so, what will the DFA look like here?

[image]

Comment: Epsilon is not a state. In the common NFA terminology, the epsilon letter is used for labeling an empty transition: a transition from one NFA state to another without the consumption of an input character.

Comment: I updated question. But still I am clueless with possible conversion here.

Comment: Try the openFST library determinize()  -- http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/FST/PythonExtension

Answer (score 4):

NFA's do not have "epsilon states". They have "epsilon transitions": transitions labeled using the epsilon letter, denoting that no input character is consumed by that transition.  An NFA graph need not contain any epsilon transitions.

Epsilon transitions are generated by a compiler which translates a regular expression to an NFA graph. They help to represent the bypass paths that correspond to optional matches.  If you have a regular expression without any optional, such as `ab`, the NFA graph doesn't (have to) contain any epsilon edges.

An important concept in NFA simulation and NFA to DFA translation is the "epsilon closure": a set of states reachable from a state by following epsilon transitions. If any state S is in the closure, and that state has an epsilon transition to some state T, then T is also in the closure. Hence "epsilon closure".

We construct sets of NFA states to deal with the ambiguity that the NFA graph has multiple transitions on the same input character to multiple states. Then we perform an epsilon closure to deal with the additional ambiguity that there are transitions without consuming an input symbol, representing optional matching.

NFA simulation constructs sets of NFA states dynamically; the NFA to DFA "subset construction" pre-computes these sets and turns them into the nodes in an a graph which is the DFA.

#### To DFA, informally, step by step.

To turn your NFA graph into a DFA, we first start with a blank slate. We hold no NFA states. The arrow tells us that the NFA begins in state 1. We ask ourselves, what NFA states are in the epsilon closure of the set which consists of state 1? And we notice: there are no epsilon transitions. So the closure set is `{ 1 }`. Our DFA machine is empty so far, so we take this set `{ 1 }` and we call that object `S0`: the initial state of our DFA.

Now that we have a DFA state, we ask ourselves: what transitions lead out of this state for each of the input alphabet characters? We first evaluate `a`. Starting with set `S0` which represents NFA states `{ 1 }`, we compute the set of NFA states which are reachable on symbol `a`.  These states are `{ 1, 2 }`, because `1` points back to itself on `a`, and also transitions to 2 on `a`.  Having this transition set, we need to take into account epsilons: we need to extend that set by computing its epsilon closure. Since there are no epsilons, there is nothing to do. We have `{ 1, 2 }` and we will call that state `S1` of the DFA. So far we have this emerging picture of the DFA:

```
      a  b    NFA set
 S0: S1  ?    { 1 }
 S1:  ?  ?    { 1, 2 }
```

We know that `S0` transitions to `S1` on `a`. We don't know yet what it does for `b`, and we haven't considered transitions out of `S1` yet.

We next move to `b` (in the context of evaluating S0). On `b`, the states reachable out of `{ 1 }` consist of the set `{ 2 }`. Again, epsilon-closing on this does nothing. And `{ 2 }` does not look like any existing DFA state, so we make a new state `S2`:

```
      a   b
 S0: S1  S2   { 1 }
 S1:  ?   ?   { 1, 2 }
 S2:  ?   ?   { 2 }
```

Now we have finished `S0`, so we move to the next unfinished state, `S1`, which consists of the NFA set `{ 1, 2 }`. We ask, which states are reachable from this set upon the consumption of `a`?  The answer is `{ 1, 2 }`.  The epsilon closure of this is `{ 1, 2 }`.  And we note: `{ 1, 2 }` is identical to `S1`. Thus, `S1` transitions to itself on `a`:

```
      a   b
 S0: S1  S2   { 1 }
 S1: S1   ?   { 1, 2 }
 S2:  ?   ?   { 2 }
```

Then we consider `S1/b`. What set is reachable from `{ 1, 2 }` on the consumption of `b`? The answer is: `{ 1, 2 }`. So, `S1` transitions to itself on `b` also.

```
      a   b
 S0: S1  S2   { 1 }
 S1: S1  S1   { 1, 2 }
 S2:  ?   ?   { 2 }
```

Now `S2/a` is interesting. The { 2 } doesn't have any transitions on `a`: the set is empty. We can represent this situation in various ways, one of which is that we create a set called `E` (error).  If `a` is seen in state S2, then it is an error; the machine doesn't accept that character.

```
      a   b
 S0: S1  S2   { 1 }
 S1: S1  S1   { 1, 2 }
 S2:  E   ?   { 2 }
  E:          { }
```

For `S2/b` we see that `{ 2 }` transitions to `{ 1 }` and that `{ 1 }` is just `S0`:

```
      a   b
 S0: S1  S2   { 1 }
 S1: S1  S1   { 1, 2 }
 S2:  E  S0   { 2 }
  E:          { }
```

If the machine gets into state `E` it is stuck there, and so we can just fill its entries like this:

```
      a   b
 S0: S1  S2   { 1 }
 S1: S1  S1   { 1, 2 }
 S2:  E  S0   { 2 }
  E:  E   E   { }
```

Lastly, we note that in the original NFA, state 2 is the acceptance state. In the DFA, therefore, any state whose NFA set contains state 2 is an acceptance state.

```
      a   b  acc?
 S0: S1  S2        { 1 }
 S1: S1  S1   y    { 1, 2 }
 S2:  E  S0   y    { 2 }
  E:  E   E        { }
```

If the machine gets into state E, that is a permanent failure. (Whoever is feeding input to the DFA might notice this situation and stop feeding it.)